# Python Data Science Question 10.14: Covid Data

Tags: python, dataframe

Im on the last part of this assigment, and I dont really know how to approach filling in the last few sections (starred)

Problem 6) Professor Derek is worried about outcomes over time for his age bracket (30-40). He wants you to plot the relative frequency of positive outcomes (y-axis) over time (x-axis) while also including 1 standard deviation above and below each point. You should not compute Spearman's correlation here. Fill in the function below.

```
def create_bar_plot_for_derek(covid19_data):
  # first we subset the data by the appropriate age bracket and do a bit of cleaning
  prof_age_data = covid19_data[covid19_data.age_range=="30-40"]
  prof_age_data=prof_age_data.replace(to_replace='25.02.2020 - 26.02.2020',value='25.02.2020')

  # and we convert the column to a date-time
  prof_age_data['date_confirmation']=pd.to_datetime(prof_age_data['date_confirmation'],dayfirst=True)

  outcomes_over_time =  **# Problem 6) fill in here**

  outcomes_over_time = outcomes_over_time.dropna() # we should drop the rows with missing values

  x =  **# Problem 6) fill in here**
  y =  **# Problem 6) fill in here**
  error =  **# Problem 6) fill in here**

  fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
  ax.errorbar(x, y, yerr=error, fmt='-o')
  plt.ylabel('Relative Frequency', fontsize=14)
  plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=14)
  return x, y, error
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask] - this isn't a code-writing or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Group the data by date_confirmation and count the number of positive outcomes (i.e., cases where the outcome is "positive"). Store this data in a new dataframe, let's call it pos_outcomes_over_time.

```
pos_outcomes_over_time = prof_age_data.groupby('date_confirmation')['outcome'].apply(lambda x: (x == 'positive').sum()).reset_index(name='num_positive')
```

**2** Compute the total number of cases for each date in the prof_age_data dataframe. Store this data in a new dataframe, let's call it total_cases_over_time.

```
total_cases_over_time = prof_age_data.groupby('date_confirmation').size().reset_index(name='num_cases')
```

**3** Merge pos_outcomes_over_time and total_cases_over_time dataframes on the date_confirmation column.

```
outcomes_over_time = pd.merge(pos_outcomes_over_time, total_cases_over_time, on='date_confirmation')
```

**4**Compute the relative frequency of positive outcomes as num_positive divided by num_cases. Store this data in a new column called rel_freq_positive.

```
outcomes_over_time['rel_freq_positive'] = outcomes_over_time['num_positive'] / outcomes_over_time['num_cases']
```

**5** Compute the mean and standard deviation of rel_freq_positive for each date in the outcomes_over_time dataframe.

```
mean_rel_freq_positive = outcomes_over_time.groupby('date_confirmation')['rel_freq_positive'].mean()
std_rel_freq_positive = outcomes_over_time.groupby('date_confirmation')['rel_freq_positive'].std()
```

**6** Create the x and y arrays for plotting, where x is the date_confirmation column and y is the mean_rel_freq_positive column.

```
x = outcomes_over_time['date_confirmation']
y = mean_rel_freq_positive
```

**7** Create the error array for plotting, where error is the std_rel_freq_positive column.

```
error = std_rel_freq_positive
```

The final implementation for the create_bar_plot_for_derek function is:

```
def create_bar_plot_for_derek(covid19_data):
  # first we subset the data by the appropriate age bracket and do a bit of cleaning
  prof_age_data = covid19_data[covid19_data.age_range=="30-40"]
  prof_age_data=prof_age_data.replace(to_replace='25.02.2020 - 26.02.2020',value='25.02.2020')

  # and we convert the column to a date-time
  prof_age_data['date_confirmation']=pd.to_datetime(prof_age_data['date_confirmation'],dayfirst=True)

  # Problem 6) plot relative frequency of positive outcomes over time with 1 standard deviation above and below each point
  pos_outcomes_over_time = prof_age_data.groupby('date_confirmation')['outcome'].apply(lambda x: (x == 'positive').sum()).reset_index(name='num_positive')
  total_cases_over_time = prof_age_data.groupby('date_confirmation').size().reset_index(name='num_cases')
  outcomes_over_time = pd.merge(pos_outcomes_over_time, total_cases_over_time, on='date_confirmation')
  outcomes_over_time['rel_freq_positive'] = outcomes_over_time['num_positive'] / outcomes_over_time['num_cases']
  mean_rel_freq_positive = outcomes_over_time.groupby('date_confirmation')['rel_freq_positive'].mean()
  std_rel_freq_positive = outcomes_over_time.groupby('date_confirmation')['rel_freq_positive'].std()
  outcomes_over_time = outcomes_over_time.dropna() #
```